# Custom components are not being rendered because problems were detected on Xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms, android-emulator, rendering

I want to make mobile app with Xamarin forms for android and IOS, When i run emulator this popup message appear :Custom components are not being rendered because problems were detected.
the output is here :
pastebin.com/9SAYtATt

Comment: Did you update to the latest nuget packages? What VS version and SO are you using?

Comment: My VS is 2019 so i updeted nuget pack

Comment: What are these third part components or custom components you are using ? w/o code, sample or context you won't get an effective answer.